Migrating tables from AWS PostgreSQL to Azure SQL database
On AWS PostgreSQL I have a server that contains 20 databases (db1, db2, etc), and in each database there are 5 tables (table 1, table 2, etc). The tables all have the same schema (table 1 from db1 has the same schema as table 1 from other dbs).
The goal is migrate this data to Azure SQL database, but ideally it combine (concatenate) the tables across all databases. So in the end, there's still 5 tables in Azure SQL, but each will have an additional column indicating the source database.
So far, I was able to connect to the PostgreSQL using Python ( psycopg2), and was able to analyzing the data in VSCode. But I've never migrated data between different databases before, let alone between clouds, and I need some guidance on what's the best way to do this.
I realize there's multiple options (like Data Factory?), but I'd like to know the most beginner friendly way.
This is an one-off thing.
Thanks
